# Error al instalar php5-pgsql en ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

Tengo un servidor Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. Versión del php: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli)
Quiero instalar php5-pgsql, uso el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Me tira el siguiente error

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-106-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic but it is not going to be installed
>    linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic but it is not going to be installed
>    php5-pgsql : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.20 is to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

He intentado con:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Pero cuando ejecuto  sudo apt-get autoremove
Me dice casi lo mismo:

> Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-106-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic but it is not installed
>    linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic but it is not installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Al ejecutar

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

> (Reading database ... 550803 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic_3.13.0-112.159_amd64.deb ...
>   Done.
>   Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic (3.13.0-112.159) ...
>   dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic_3.13.0-112.159_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
>   Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic
>   Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic_3.13.0-106.153_amd64.deb ...
>   Done.
>   Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic (3.13.0-106.153) ...
>   dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic_3.13.0-106.153_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.13.0-106-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.13.0-106-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
>   dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
>   Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-106-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-106-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-106-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-106-generic
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic_3.13.0-112.159_amd64.deb
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic_3.13.0-106.153_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque la pregunta no se trata sobre programación.

Comment: Yo te aconsejo instalar synaptic, e instalar esos paquetes problemáticos desde su interfaz gráfica. Él te resolverá todos los conflictos que apt por sí mismo no sabe como resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave está en la salida de `sudo apt-get -f install` en una parte sale:

```
failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
```

Eso indica que no te queda espacio en el disco (confírmalo con `df -h`). Te recomendaría que uses [baobab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab) para ver que carpetas son las que tienen más información, [bleachbit](http://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux) también es una buena opción para borrar basura del disco.

Answer (score 1):

El mismo error te da la solución:

> You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.

Que traducido sería algo como:

> Debes correr / ejecutar ‘apt-get -f install‘ para corregir los errores.

Comment: Se me olvido poner, al ejecutar 'apt-get -f install' me tira

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic_3.13.0-112.159_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic_3.13.0-106.153_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)